# Disable the -n for pyexiftool such that fields like LensID are formatted for human reading

Tags: printing, disable, exiftool

I use this code to read a directory with camera raw files

```
with exiftool.ExifToolHelper(logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)) as et:
    metadata = et.get_metadata(config["files"]["PictureDirectory"], params=SELECTED_FIELDS)
```

I cannot find how I can pass something like

```
#exiftool.ExifToolHelper.__init__(True, True, True, common_args=['-G'])
```

to override the defalt -n option.

Any help is appreciated.

I did not find out how to pass the common_args=['-G'] to override he default -n

Answer (score 1):

The `-n` option cannot be overridden, so you can't exclude a single tag when extracting all data. It can be activated on a per tag basis by appending a hash tag to the end if a tag name e.g `-TAG#`, but that requires listing only specific tags, not all of them.

To override PYExiftool's default use of `-n`, see the [FAQ under "Ways to make the ouptut match"](https://sylikc.github.io/pyexiftool/faq.html#ways-to-make-the-ouptut-match)

- Disable print conversion and group name in PyExifTool:

`import exiftool`
`with exiftool.ExifTool(common_args=None) as et:`
       `print(et.execute("-JFIF:all", "rose.jpg"))`